# Are rack and pinion parts unavailable?

Tags: steering

Is it my poor googling skills, or does nobody sell individual parts for rack and pinion steering units?

The pinion has a chipped tooth but the rack looks tip top, so I see no reason to spend $250 replacing the whole system.

Is there some trick to searching for rack/pinion assembly parts?

Comment: How bad is the chipped tooth?

Comment: @Moab doesn't even look chipped or *look* worn, but there's a clear point of slop when it comes around, just from manipulating it off the car. The slop location is at dead center where the wheel is when going straight.  I flipped it 180 degrees and the point of slop moves with it, i.e. When the wheel is upside down.   The car has 250k miles.

Comment: Yep sounds like the rack gear is worn in the straight ahead position, replace the rack.

Answer (score 2):

They used to be, but given the popularity of reconditioned units which are offered with a guarantee and the time needed to strip and rebuild a unit it is quicker to fit a complete unit.

If you wish to rebuild yours then finding a second hand unit with a good pinion may be a possibility...

Answer (score 1):

The increase in the availability of commercially rebuilt units at a reasonable price is the likely cause of difficulty finding parts. As independent garages fight to maintain profitability getting the job finished and paid for quickly is a priority. The time to remove, disassemble,  inspect, order parts, wait for delivery, etc. would tie up the customers' car and a lift for a longer than acceptable time. The labor rate a mass rebuilder pays is likely far less than that of an experienced tech. The fewer places sourcing parts means they are harder to locate.

Comment: The rebuilders have to have a source for their parts, but it doesn't seem like they're available at retail.